# Reading Row data from Spark Dataset in Loop

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to read spark dataset rows in loop with Java and I have to read other datasets inside.

Suppose ds is the dataset and if write loop as below I can read other datasets

```
ds.toJavaRDD().collect().forEach()
```

but I remove collect() and JavaRDD() and directly apply

```
ds.foreach()
```

then I am not able to read other datasets. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more that what you are doing inside `foreach()`? Because there is nothing wrong with `ds.foreach()`, alternatively if you want your function to return some value, you can use `map` function as well

Comment: @ShashwatSharma I just want to read the row data and based on this row data I would like to extract some more data from a other dataset. That dataset is null inside this loop.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a dataset (lets say from HDFS or a local file system) is an operation that is started from within the [driver process](https://blog.knoldus.com/understanding-the-working-of-spark-driver-and-executor/). Any code running within an executor process cannot use the [SparkSession](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html), this API only lives on the driver.

The difference between `ds.toJavaRDD().collect().forEach(myFunction)` and `ds.foreach(myFunction)` is that in the first statement `myFunction` is executed within the driver process and in the second one `myFunction` is executed within an executor process and therefore the Spark-API cannot be used.

[ds.toJavaRDD().collect()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#collect--) returns a plain Java List object, all data of the Spark dataset is moved to the driver. This list is a standard Java object that lives within the driver process. [foreach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is here a method from the [java.lang.Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

[ds.foreach()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#foreach-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction-) on the other hand is a method of [Spark dataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) and its parameter method will be executed in parallel within the different Spark executors.